# Taurus docker image with S3 config file

Tags: taurus

I'm looking for a way to run Taurus docker container, having the YML file pulled from S3

I saw the https://hub.docker.com/r/blazemeter/taurus/dockerfile/, it seems that it is not supported

Are you aware of any option supporting that?